# Desktop and desktop.browse are supported, but browse still hangs

Tags: java, url, web, desktop

I'm trying to open a link in the default browser from Java. I do not want to create a simple web browser, I want to use an existing one. People have suggested to use the following:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.targetsite.com"));
```

However, this simply hangs upon calling `browse`, and I end up having to force quit.

I saw a suggestion to run the following, to find out if Desktop and desktop.browse should be working on my system:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    System.out.println("Desktop IS supported on this platform ");
    if (Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        System.out.println("Action BROWSE  IS supported on this platform ");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Action BROWSE  ISN'T supported on this platform ");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("Desktop ISN'T supported on this platform ");
}
```

which gave the output:

```
Desktop IS supported on this platform 
Action BROWSE  IS supported on this platform
```

What can I do to fix, or work around this?

Using Java 1.8.0_73

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @whiskeyspider Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you did everything correctly and your code should work as expected in Windows and OS X.  Not surprisingly support for `Desktop` in Linux is not that great.  You can try an alternative approach:

```
if (Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "which", "xdg-open" }).getInputStream().read() != -1) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "xdg-open", urlString });
}
```

Comment: This is almost good, but leaves an InputStream open that you should close.