# Is Desktop#browse supported on Linux platform just for Gnome desktop?

Tags: java, awt, deadlock, gnome, manjaro

Running my Java application with this code:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
{
    Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
    try
    {
        d.browse(new URI("someurl")); // someurl is just an example, I am opening real url
    }
    catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e)
    {
        logger.warn(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
    }
}
```

results in application not responding (probably deadlock) on Manjaro Linux KDE. While it works with no problem on Windows, I do not want to check for OS in my application and allow it just for Windows. I have not tried other platforms yet.

What i use:

- Adoptium JDK 11
- Manjaro kernel 5.10.83-1-MANJARO 64bit
- KDE Plasma 5.23.4
- Qt 5.15.2

*Detailed deadlock location:*

`Desktop` class:

```
public void browse(URI uri) throws IOException {
        checkAWTPermission();
        checkExec();
        checkActionSupport(Action.BROWSE);
        Objects.requireNonNull(uri);
        peer.browse(uri); // <- goes here
    }
```

Deadlock happens in `XDesktopPeer` class that implements `DesktopPeer` interface (*peer*) on method `gnome_url_show(...)`:

```
private void launch(URI uri) throws IOException {
        byte[] uriByteArray = ( uri.toString() + '\0' ).getBytes();
        boolean result = false;
        XToolkit.awtLock();
        try {
            if (!nativeLibraryLoaded) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to load native libraries.");
            }
            result = gnome_url_show(uriByteArray); // <- deadlock / app not responding here
        } finally {
            XToolkit.awtUnlock();
        }
        if (!result) {
            throw new IOException("Failed to show URI:" + uri);
        }
    }
```

So... is Desktop#browse supported on Linux platform just for Gnome desktop?

I am guessing this, because of that method name.

*If yes, can I make a check for deadlock around my code, so I prevent this in my app? rather than checking for OS and distros?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are already several questions on SO about that issue:

- [Desktop.getDesktop().browse Hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879854/desktop-getdesktop-browse-hangs)
- [Desktop and desktop.browse are supported, but browse still hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37926495/desktop-and-desktop-browse-are-supported-but-browse-still-hangs)
- [Desktop browse does not work in java for Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21933442/desktop-browse-does-not-work-in-java-for-ubuntu)

There is also this discussion:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1574879

where someone says:

> gnome_url_show is actually in libgnome-2-0 package

So, if the package is missing, `Desktop.browse()` will fail. There are 2 solutions to fix that.

### Solution 1

Install the libgnome package.

### Solution 2

Execute xdg-open to open the URL, e.g.:

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"xdg-open", someurl});
```